# JavaFX JAR artifact adding media leads to main class error

Tags: java, javafx

If I add some media (pictures and/or sounds) my JavaFX artifact won't launch.

Im using macOS and IntelliJ. Launching the .jar from Terminal returns "Error: Could not find or load main class". However, this only occurs with pictures I stored in variables but haven't included yet (for ex. a PlayerIcon) so it isn't a manifest issue.

I installed Java 8 because I got so many issues with Java 10, 11 and 12. Inside of IntelliJ the project launches normally, just the exported .jar is affected of the issue. I am new to JavaFX and I did not include a FXML file. Maybe that's the issue?

Heres a code snippet of how I included one image:

```
Image Scoreboard = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Scoreboard.png"));
ScoreBoardContainer.setImage(Scoreboard);
Group root = new Group();
root.getChildren().add(ScoreBoardContainer);
Scene GameUI = new Scene(root, w, h);
```

Thanks for your help!

Longer code snippet:

```
package sample;
import ...

public class Main extends Application {

...variables...

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

final ImageView HintergrundMuster = new ImageView();
final ImageView ScoreBoardContainer = new ImageView();
Image HG = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("space-background.png"));
Image PlanetBraun = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Planet.png"));
Image Scoreboard = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Scoreboard.png"));

HintergrundMuster.setImage(HG);
ScoreBoardContainer.setImage(Scoreboard);

AudioClip SprungSound = new AudioClip(new File("jump.mp3").toURI().toString());
SprungSound.play(0);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b,h);
Vordergrund = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

Group root = new Group();
root.getChildren().add(HintergrundMuster);
root.getChildren().add(canvas);
root.getChildren().add(ScoreBoardContainer);

Scene GameUI = new Scene(root, b, h);

primaryStage.setTitle(„Test“);
primaryStage.setScene(GameUI);
primaryStage.show();
...
```

Comment: Your code snippet will only work if you have also packaged the Scoreboard.png at the right location inside of your jar. All resources that you access this way must be packaged into the jar.

Comment: QQ: Any reasons why you've decided to use JavaFX? If you want to write UI there are better/modern/popular alternatives.

Comment: @mipa This png file works fine. I think that is not the issue since it gets displayed all the time...

Comment: @Tomer I wanted to develop a simple 2d game in Java just to "re-learn" the language. If you have any suggestions for Java 2d game development, Id be happy to hear about it!

Comment: How could the image be displayed if you're getting a "could not find or load main class" error? The application isn't even launching. What does the manifest look like? Can you provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @Slaw The jar file starts and displays the added background images. However, if I add more images, it won't launch anymore. Also, everything works fine and gets displayed starting the application from IntelliJ. Only the exported jar file is not working properly. The content of the manifest is: "Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: sample.Main"

Comment: @Slaw I just edited the post and included a longer code snippet.

Comment: For me in java 9 or 10 relative resource paths stopped working. Try with complete resource paths starting at the classpath root (e.g. `/my/package/scene.fxml`). Furthermore `-` may be a problem. Make sure all directory and file names are valid java identifiers...

Comment: @fabian Thanks, just tried that, but sadly, it didn't work

Comment: I just found out that some pictures work while others produce a crash of the program. However, I can't find a difference between the pictures. They are all in PNG format and kind of the same size (just a few KB)

Comment: @fabian Just found out that some of the pictures had the file ending .PNG while others had .png. Changing all in .png did the trick. However, the program still doesn't launch with the audio files included. Maybe the path to them is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution to my problem. Thanks for your help anyway!

I overlooked that some of my files had the .PNG format while others had .png. For IntelliJ, this doesn't matter, but for the JAR compiler it does indeed matter apparently.

Also, I had a problem with my audio files so I copied them into my "sample" folder and changed the code a little bit. Following snipped worked for me:

```
 AudioClip SprungSound = new AudioClip(this.getClass().getResource("jump.mp3").toString());
```